# Find difference between sets of objects

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 objects and would like to find the difference between them. Return an array or object of the differences only. The two objects look as following.

```
{
    "new": {
        "crc_code": "00",
        "serial_number": "239-03",
        "reason": "Ir/b4c - no center rib",
        "project_id": 9,
        "wafer_id": 1,
        "equipment_status_code_id": 7,
        "plate_container_id": null,
        "supplier_id": 1,
        "container_slot_id": null,
        "plate_quality_id": 1
    },
    "old": {
        "crc_code": "00",
        "serial_number": "239-03",
        "reason": "Ir/b4c - no center rib",
        "project_id": 9,
        "wafer_id": 1,
        "equipment_status_code_id": 2,
        "plate_container_id": null,
        "supplier_id": 1,
        "container_slot_id": null,
        "plate_quality_id": 2
    }
}
```

What's the best way to go about this?

**Update** People asking what I have tried already?

Something along these lines.

```
array_udiff($new, $old, function ($obj_a, $obj_b) {
                    return  strcmp($obj_a, $obj_b);
                }
            );
```

But not getting there..

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: what difference you want to find here ? what is expected output ?

Comment: Do you want the difference between the values of objects? or the keys which are present in one object and not in other?

Comment: @tejuc value difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_diff_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php):

```
return array_diff_assoc($obj->new, $obj->old);
```

Comment: Not a php geek here. ```array_diff_assoc($old->new, $new->old);``` is not getting me anywhere. However, removing new and old is returning results.

Answer (score 1):

```
// convert object to array
$arr = json_decode(json_encode($obj), true);

// get the diff
$diff = array_diff($arr['new'], $arr['old']);

// result
array:1 [
  "equipment_status_code_id" => 7
]
```